# Filemaker xml export of related items

Tags: xml, filemaker

I spend some time searching the stackoveflow databases; couldn't find an example to help with the following. This is the FMP export:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<DATABASE>catalogus.fmp12</DATABASE>
<LAYOUT>items</LAYOUT>
<ROW MODID="178" RECORDID="560">
<sub_group>This is the title</sub_group>
<description>This is the description</description>
<item_number><DATA>010050</DATA><DATA>010350</DATA></item_number>
<item_name><DATA>UNIVERSAL PUMP</DATA><DATA>SPARE PARTS SET</DATA></item_name>
</ROW>
</FMPDSORESULT>
```

All works well by the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult" exclude-result-prefixes="fm">
<xsl:output version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml' />
<xsl:template match="/">
<items>
<xsl:for-each select="fm:FMPDSORESULT/fm:ROW">
<item>
<sub_group>
<xsl:value-of select="./fm:sub_group" />
</sub_group>
<description>
<xsl:value-of select="./fm:description" />
</description>
<subitems>
<xsl:for-each select="?????????????????????">
<related>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</related>
</xsl:for-each>
</subitems>
</item>
</xsl:for-each>
</items>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item>
<sub_group>This is the title</sub_group>
<description>This is the description</description>
<subitems>
</subitems>
</item>
</items>
```

I hoped to get something like:

```
This is the title
This is the description
010050 Universal Pump
010350 Spare Parts Set
```

What should be the correct formatting to pick up those related values?
Help is appreciated. For me this xml/InDesign project is a perfect way to get more familiar with xml.

Comment: "*All works well by the stylesheet*" No, I don't think so. The export that you show us was made using the FMPXMLRESULT grammar; your stylesheet is built upon the FMPDSORESULT grammar - therefore the result will be an empty <items/> element.

Comment: corrections has been made!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the exact format you want for your output. Try replacing the problematic part:

```
<subitems>
<xsl:for-each select="?????????????????????">
<related>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</related>
</xsl:for-each>
</subitems>
```

with:

```
<subitems>
    <xsl:for-each select="fm:item_number/fm:DATA">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <subitem>
        <item_number>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </item_number>
        <item_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../fm:item_name/fm:DATA[$i]"/>
        </item_name>
        </subitem>
    </xsl:for-each>
</subitems>
```

This should produce the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <sub_group>This is the title</sub_group>
    <description>This is the description</description>
    <subitems>
      <subitem>
        <item_number>010050</item_number>
        <item_name>UNIVERSAL PUMP</item_name>
      </subitem>
      <subitem>
        <item_number>010350</item_number>
        <item_name>SPARE PARTS SET</item_name>
      </subitem>
    </subitems>
  </item>
</items>
```

Comment: I think that's it Michael. I just implemented in the final stylesheet and after some tweeks  in InDesign  the data flows in perfectly. Thanks again!